# I get the output True even though it should be False

Tags: python

Create a function that takes a number as input and returns True if the sum of its digits has the same parity as the entire number. Otherwise, return False.

e.g.

`parity_function(243)` --> `True`

`243` is odd and so is `9 (2 + 4 + 3)`

```
def par_analy(num):
    x = str(num)
    sum = int(x[0])
    if len(x)!=1:
        for i in range(1,len(x)):
            sum += int(x[i])
        par = num % 2
        sumi = sum % 2
        if par and sumi == 0:
            return True
        elif par and sumi !=0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return True
print(par_analy(13))
```

The output is `True` even though both `par` and `sumi` don't equal `0` or equal `0`

[image: screenshot of code debugging in vs code]

Comment: `if par and sumi == 0:` means `if (par) and (sumi == 0):`. You might want something like `if par==0 and sumi==0:` ?

Comment: Since everyone seems to be trying to write shorter code in the answers, I'd like to present my solution for the function body. One line of code: `return sum(map(int, str(num))) % 2 == num % 2`.

Comment: We can get to another shortened form by noticing that "parity of the number =parity of the digit sum" is true if and only if the sum of all the digits *excluding the last digit* is even. So a solution is: `return not sum(map(int, str(num)[:-1])) % 2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
def par_analy(num):
    x = str(num)
    sum = int(x[0])
    if len(x)!=1:
        for i in range(1,len(x)):
            sum += int(x[i])
        par = num % 2
        sumi = sum % 2
        if par == 0 and sumi == 0:
            return True
        elif par != 0 and sumi !=0:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return True
print(par_analy(13))
```

When you write something like `if par and sumi == 0` you're saying that `par` has a truthy value, and sumi is zero.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Python function that takes a number as input and returns True if the sum of its digits has the same parity as the entire number, and False otherwise:

```
def parity_function(num):
    digit_sum = sum(int(digit) for digit in str(num))
    return num % 2 == digit_sum % 2
```

Here's how it works:

- The str(num) call converts the input number to a string so we can iterate over its digits using a loop.
- The int(digit) conversion inside the loop converts each digit from a string to an integer.
- The sum() function adds up all the digits.
- The expression num % 2 == digit_sum % 2 compares the parity (evenness or oddness) of the input number num to the parity of the digit sum digit_sum, and returns True if they are the same and False if they are different.

Note that this function assumes that the input is a positive integer. If you need to handle negative integers or other types of input, you may need to add additional error checking code.

Answer (score 0):

```
def par_analy(num):
    x = str(num)
    total_sum = 0
    for i in range(len(x)):
        total_sum += int(x[i])
    parity = num % 2
    sum_parity = total_sum % 2
    return parity == sum_parity
```

elif par and sumi !=0: return True
Shouldn't you be returning False in this case?

Answer (score 0):

```
def parity_function(n):
# Convert the number to a string to extract its digits
digit_str = str(n)

# Calculate the sum of the digits
digit_sum = sum(int(d) for d in digit_str)

# Check if both the number and the sum of its digits have the same 
parity
return (n % 2 == 0) == (digit_sum % 2 == 0)

# Test the function
print(parity_function(243))  # True
```

This function first converts the input number n into a string to extract its digits. Then, it calculates the sum of these digits using a generator expression inside the sum() function. Finally, it checks if both the original number and the digit sum have the same parity (even or odd) by comparing their remainders when divided by 2. If the remainders are the same, the function returns True, otherwise False.